# Azure Media Service authentication type

Tags: .net, azure, rest, azure-media-services

Azure Media Service is deprecating the Access Control service-based authentication in favor of AAD authentication (more info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-media-service-aad-auth-and-acs-deprecation/). However, I'm not really sure which type of authentication I'm currently using and whether or not I will be affected by the deprecation.

This is how I currently authenticate to Azure Media Service. Is this AAD or Access Control authentication?

```
CloudMediaContext mediaContext = new CloudMediaContext(AMSAccountName, AMSAccountKey);
var asset = mediaContext.Assets.Create(fileName, AssetCreationOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is how I currently authenticate to Azure Media Service. Is this AAD or Access Control authentication?

You could get the answer from the [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-media-service-aad-auth-and-acs-deprecation/), you are using the ACS token authentication model ("account keys"). Microsoft Azure Media Services will end support for Microsoft Azure Access Control Service (ACS)-based authentication on **June 22, 2018**

> we strongly recommend that you update your code and migrate from ACS to AAD-based authentication by **June 22, 2018**.

New way of authenticating with an AAD Service Principal and client

```
var tokenCredentials = new AzureAdTokenCredentials("{YOUR AAD TENANT DOMAIN HERE}", new AzureAdClientSymmetricKey("{YOUR CLIENT ID HERE}", {YOUR CLIENT SECRET}"), AzureEnvironments.AzureCloudEnvironment);
var tokenProvider = new AzureAdTokenProvider(tokenCredentials);
var mediaContext = new CloudMediaContext(_mediaServicesApiServerUri, tokenProvider);
mediaContext.Assets.FirstOrDefault();
```

How to registry an app in the Azure AD and create service principal for accessing the resource. For more detail information, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application). Then you could get the clientId, clientSecret,tenantId.